# Is there any way to extract some key, value pairs from nested map that have both map and list children in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have a nested map which is the result of an API like below:

```json
{
  "code": 200,
  "status_message": "OK",
  "category_list": [
      {
        "category_name": "fragile",
        "results": [
            {
              "item_id": "001A",
              "item_name": "glass",
              "certificate_id": "A9812EJ0D7CBN12109"
            },
            {
              "item_id": "002A",
              "item_name": "porcelain",
              "certificate_id": "BCQ8018347503048P1"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
        "category_name": "hard",
        "results": [
            {
              "item_id": "001B",
              "item_name": "rock",
              "certificate_id": "P1024184INDHDGA831"
            },
            {
              "item_id": "002B",
              "item_name": "diamond",
              "certificate_id": "YDQI3910371H7D39ZX"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I just need to extract the `item_name` and the `item_id` from the `result` of the fragile items only, so the expected output would be like this:

```json
{
  "code": 200,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "001A",
      "name": "glass"
    },
    {
      "id": "002A",
      "name": "porcelain"
    },
  ]
}
```

Suppose that I store the result of API (the first JSON) in a variable named `apiResult` which is the `Map` type. Here is what I have done to obtain the data:

```java
List results = ((Map) ((List) apiResult.get("category_list")).get(0)).get("results");
List results = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object r : results) {
    Map inner = new HashMap();
    inner.put("name", r.get("item_name"));
    inner.put("id", r.get("item_id"));
    finalResult.add(inner);
}
Map result = new HashMap();
result.put("code", 200);
result.put("results", finalResult);
return result;
```

Is there anyway to flatten the map or simplifying the process so when it's more nested and complicated combination of Objects and Arrays in the JSON, it can handle it a bit more efficiently?

Comment: The proper way with Java is to use object mapping, rather than dealing with raw `Map`/`List`. Write classes corresponding to your JSON structure, deserialize your JSON into those classes and code will be much easier to read and write.

Comment: Is it a school assignment where you are required to tinker with raw maps/lists and avoid using object-oriented approach?  The expected output seems to comply with the code as soon as all the compilation errors about missing casting are resolved.  So it is not quite clear which hypothetical map you need to flatten and which result is expected.

Comment: @AlexRudenko No. It's not school assignment. But I just don't know yet if there's another way to do this.

Comment: @vbezhenar u mean making a POJO for it? I have thought about it before, but why is it necessary to create a class that is just used once? Could you please elaborate it in the answer?